# sending data with cc2510

Tags: rf, wireless, communication, radio, protocol

Hy, I'm trying to send simple 1 Byte package with cc2510dk-mini. The idea is to press button on on device and the led on the other lights up. I'm stuck with the problem, when I try to send data, radio goes to underflow and just sends preamble.

here is my code (written in IAR)

```
#include <ioCC2510.h>
#include <ioCC2510_bitdef.h>

unsigned int i,s_1,s_2;

int S1(void){

if(P1_2 == 0){
   for(i=0;i<2000;i++);
   if(P1_2 == 0){
     return 1;
     }
   else 
     return 0;
 }
 else
   return 0;

}

int S2(void){

if(P1_3 == 0){
  for(i=0;i<20000;i++);
  if(P1_3 == 0){
   return 1;
   }
  else 
    return 0;
  }
else
  return 0;  

}

int main(void)
{ 


P1DIR       =0x03;
P1_0 = 0;
P1_1 = 0;

// Set the system clock source to HS XOSC and max CPU speed,
// ref. [clk]=>[clk_xosc.c]

SLEEP &= ~SLEEP_OSC_PD;
while( !(SLEEP & SLEEP_XOSC_S) );
CLKCON = (CLKCON & ~(CLKCON_CLKSPD | CLKCON_OSC)) | CLKSPD_DIV_1;
while (CLKCON & CLKCON_OSC);
SLEEP |= SLEEP_OSC_PD;


/* Setup radio with settings from SmartRF® Studio. The default settings are
 * used, except that "unmodulated" is chosen in the "Simple RX tab". This
 * results in an umodulated carrier with a frequency of approx. 2.433 GHz.
 */

FSCTRL1   = 0x0A;   // Frequency synthesizer control.
FSCTRL0   = 0x00;   // Frequency synthesizer control.
FREQ2     = 0x5D;   // Frequency control word, high byte.
FREQ1     = 0x93;   // Frequency control word, middle byte.
FREQ0     = 0xB1;   // Frequency control word, low byte.
MDMCFG4   = 0x86;   // Modem configuration.
MDMCFG3   = 0x83;   // Modem configuration.
MDMCFG2   = 0x30;   // Modem configuration.
MDMCFG1   = 0x22;   // Modem configuration.
MDMCFG0   = 0xF8;   // Modem configuration.
CHANNR    = 0x00;   // Channel number.
DEVIATN   = 0x00;   // Modem deviation setting (when FSK modulation is enabled).
FREND1    = 0x56;   // Front end RX configuration.
FREND0    = 0x10;   // Front end RX configuration.
MCSM0     = 0x14;   // Main Radio Control State Machine configuration.
FOCCFG    = 0x16;   // Frequency Offset Compensation Configuration.
BSCFG     = 0x6C;   // Bit synchronization Configuration.
AGCCTRL2  = 0x03;   // AGC control.
AGCCTRL1  = 0x40;   // AGC control.
AGCCTRL0  = 0x91;   // AGC control.
FSCAL3    = 0xA9;   // Frequency synthesizer calibration.
FSCAL2    = 0x0A;   // Frequency synthesizer calibration.
FSCAL1    = 0x00;   // Frequency synthesizer calibration.
FSCAL0    = 0x11;   // Frequency synthesizer calibration.
TEST2     = 0x88;   // Various test settings.
TEST1     = 0x31;   // Various test settings.
TEST0     = 0x09;   // Various test settings.
PA_TABLE0 = 0xFE;   // PA output power setting.
PKTCTRL1  = 0x00;   // Packet automation control.
PKTCTRL0  = 0x00;   // Packet automation control.
ADDR      = 0x00;   // Device address.
PKTLEN    = 0x01;   // Packet length.
MCSM1     = 0x30;
/* Settings not from SmartRF® Studio. Setting both sync word registers to
 * 0xAA = 0b10101010, i.e., the same as the preamble pattern. Not necessary,
 * but gives control of what the radio attempts to transmit.
 */
SYNC1     = 0xAA;
SYNC0     = 0xAA;

//RFD = 0x00;


while (1){

  s_1 = S1();
  s_2 = S2();

  while( ( s_1 == S1() )  &&   ( s_2 == S2() ) ); 



  if(s_1){
                /* Put radio in TX. */
              RFST      = RFST_STX;


              /* Wait for radio to enter TX. */

               while (!(RFTXRXIF));

               RFD = 0x01;

               RFTXRXIF &= 1;


              //for(i=0;i<60000;i++);
              P1_0 = 1;
              //RFST = RFST_SIDLE;

        }
  else
      {
              RFST      = RFST_STX;


              /* Wait for radio to enter TX. */

               while (!(RFTXRXIF));

               RFD = 0x00;

               RFTXRXIF &= 1;

               P1_0 = 0;
      }

  if(s_2){
               RFST      = RFST_STX;


              /* Wait for radio to enter TX. */

               while (!(RFTXRXIF));

               RFD = 0x02; 

               RFTXRXIF &= 1;

                P1_1 = 1;

              //RFST = RFST_SIDLE;
              //while ((MARCSTATE & MARCSTATE_MARC_STATE) != MARC_STATE_ENDCAL);
        }

 else
      {

              RFST      = RFST_STX;


              /* Wait for radio to enter TX. */

               while (!(RFTXRXIF));

               RFD = 0x00; 

               RFTXRXIF &= 1;

                P1_1 = 0;

        }


  if(RFIF_IRQ_TXUNF){
    while(1){
      P1_0 = ~P1_0;
      P1_1 = ~P1_1;
      for(i=0;i<10000;i++);
    }
  }



}

return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not familiar with that chip but i have an experience with cc1101. I dont know what your settings does but putting a summary of the smartrf configuration will greatly help people give suggestions.

Looking at the code, it seems that you are not placing any data on the tx buffer hence you get the underflow. What i normally do is place the data on the tx buffer then i strobe the radio to tx. I hope cc1101  share the same similarities with the one you are using.